# StgCreateDocfile, etc. on MacOS 10.9.5

Tags: xcode, osx-mavericks

I'm having trouble linking an Xcode project using the AAF SDK, with Xcode 5.1.1 on MacOS 10.9.5. When I link the main dynamic library, these symbols come up missing:

`_StgCreateDocfile
_StgCreateDocfileOnILockBytes
_StgOpenStorage
_StgOpenStorageOnILockBytes
AssertProc`

I can't find a definition for them anywhere in the entire source tree for the SDK. The first four appear to be part of Structured Storage on Windows. A Structured Storage library is provided in the SDK and I'm already linking that.

Can anyone tell me of a Mac system library that defines these? Or is there a linker argument that pulls in a library for them? Thanks for any help.

Comment: You might have better luck getting an answer if you tag this question with the SDK you're using. Xcode is an IDE, and has nothing to do with whatever SDK you're trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

A late answer (!), but in case anyone comes across this...  The solution is either:

1. To use the makefiles with the AAF SDK to generate the AAF dylib,
   which works fine. or...
2. If you use Xcode to build the AAF SDK, ensure the correct
   `#defines` are kept, namely:

   `_DEBUG` `OM_DEBUG` `OM_STACK_TRACE_ON_ASSERT` `OM_USE_SCHEMASOFT_SS` `OM_STRUCTURED_STORAGE`

   Note that `DEBUG=1` is absent (it is added by default by Xcode) - if defined, this brings in `AssertProc`.  Define `NDEBUG` on release builds and omit the debug defines.
   The Stg... functions are part of the MS implementation of Structured storage as you stated, but should not be referenced on a Mac, the Schemasoft implementation being used.